# Inequalities in Implications

Tags: logic

I am facing some problems understanding the solution to part d of this question from MIT-OCW 6.402 problem set 2:

Problem 1. [12 points] Define a 3-chain to be a (not necessarily contiguous) subsequence
of three integers, which is either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing. We
will show here that any sequence of five distinct integers will contain a 3-chain. Write
the sequence as a1, a2, a3, a4, a5. Note that a monotonically increasing sequences is one in
which each term is greater than or equal to the previous term. Similarly, a monotonically
decreasing sequence is one in which each term is less than or equal to the previous term.
Lastly, a subsequence is a sequence derived from the original sequence by deleting some
elements without changing the location of the remaining elements.
(a) [4 pts] Assume that a1 < a2. Show that if there is no 3-chain in our sequence, then a3
must be less than a1. (Hint: consider a4!)
(b) [2 pts] Using the previous part, show that if a1 < a2 and there is no 3-chain in our
sequence, then a3 < a4 < a2.
(c) [2 pts] Assuming that a1 < a2 and a3 < a4 < a2, show that any value of a5 must result
in a 3-chain.
(d) [4 pts] Using the previous parts, prove by contradiction that any sequence of five distinct
integers must contain a 3-chain.

The answer states:
Solution: From the previous parts, we see that assuming that a1 < a2, any choice of
a5 must result in a 3-chain. However, the other case, that a1 > a2, results in the same
argument; one only needs to reverse the > and < signs. So any choice of a5 results in a
3-chain in that case as well. What we have been doing is assuming that we could construct
such a five-integer sequence, and going through the steps to construct it. Because the only
results from such a construction contain 3-chains, we reach a contradiction, and conclude
that all sequences of five distinct integers must contain a 3-chain.

My questions:

1. Why did the inequality signs reverse in the implications when I reversed the inequality signs in the assumption a1 < a2 to become a1 > a2.
2. Does this reversal of inequality sign in an implication hold true even when the numbers are not distinct? Or does it only hold in this case where they are distinct.

Comment: Consider that "monotonicalli increasing" means $\le$. Thus, $a_1 \le a_2$ behaves exactly as $a_1 < a_2$.

Comment: I mean that $a_1=a_2=a_3$ is a $3$-chain.